# How to select elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am trying to use AngularJS to grab the element by tag name.

For example,

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('h1')).css('color', 'green');
```

element in HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
</div>
```

It works only for the first element but not the second one. I am not sure the reason for it. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The reason is that `querySelector()` selects first matching element. You can use `querySelectorAll` to select all matched elements, loop over them and apply styles. However, I'd suggest to use `ng-class` with a flag on those elements.

Comment: why are you trying to do this? Angular is not jQuery. Just use ng-class

Comment: If it's like you describe, maybe you should also be using `ng-repeat` as in `<div ng-repeat="title in titles"><h1 ng-class="{'color': title.color}">{{title.text}}</h1></div>`. It depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but make sure you're trying to do things the "Angular" way. See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tushar mentioned, the best way to handle this is with ng-class.  Let Angular do the DOM manipulation for you

Your CSS

```
.someclass{
  color: green
}
```

Your HTML

```
<div ng-class="{'someclass': obj.value == 'somevalue'}">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
</div>
```

After `'someclass'`, in your controller, you can insert whatever expression makes the most sense.  When your expression evaluates to true, the `'someclass'` will be applied to your Div.

Answer (score 1):

The [`querySelector()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

The [`querySelectorAll()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector(s), as a static `NodeList` object.

Comment: That explains why the code is not working, but doesn't provide solution.